# custom loss function for determine trend of numbers in keras lstm

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function

i am new in python.
i want to make a custom loss function that calculates the trend of a sequence of number (y_true) and compares it to the predicted trend of another sequence of number that knows as prediction and at the end, calculates the loss of those input and output sequences trend.
how i should do it?
here is my code.

```
def custom_loss_(y_true, y_pred):
    
        actual = y_true[1] - y_true[0]
        predicted = y_pred[1] - y_true[0]
        
        loss = (actual - predicted)
        return loss
```

Comment: Your code produces a single number based on the difference between the change from the first and second element of each sequence. Is that what you want?

Comment: something like that which you said. but, i want to cause to understand that to the custom loss function that calculates my model loss based on that.